# Drupal how to blog related content from one drupal site to other

Tags: php, drupal

I have an old Drupal site with customized Layouts by taking a basic theme and adding modules. Now I am trying to change theme which has predefined modules and using the completely new database.

How can I port blog related content, along with all custom fields, into my new database? As I am new to Drupal I cannot find the exact way to do it. I tried to copy directly from the database but the data did not port properly and it is breaking.

Comment: Are you changing between major versions?  If so, what version of Drupal is the original site and what are you using on the new edition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are comfortable writing custom Drupal code you could use the Drupal [migrate](https://www.drupal.org/project/migrate) module to migrate content from Drupal to Drupal. There are quite some good resources about this topic.

https://drupalize.me/blog/201608/custom-drupal-drupal-migrations-migrate-tools

Alternatavily you can use the Drupal feeds module as described in this question: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/25968/46398 where you could import content using the RSS feed.